# Update android app data from server

Tags: android

Actually I searched a lot on Google and here on Stackoverflow for my problem but could not get the results I needed.
So here is my question - I am building an android app. I want my app data to be updated dynamically from the server. Please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this.

**Storing data**

- Use a Database
- Store objects in filesystem
- Store key-value sets in SharedPreferences

You can make utilization of databases easier by using database access object frameworks, e.g. GreenDAO or object relationship mappers, e.g. ORMLite.

**Communication**

Active polling vs. push:

If you want to sync "Whenever data is available", you require *push* functionality. This can be achieved by utilizing Google Cloud Messaging, which is available for devices sporting Play Services.

If you just want to sync "whenever the user opens the app" you can use polling.

1. Check connectivity
2. You create
   a [HTTP client](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) and GET your messages in something that does not block your UI Thread, e.g AsyncTask doInBackground(...). If it is a very long running operation, you should use a Service instead.
3. Use the reply to Create/Remove/Update/Delete the data you stored
4. Deliver results to the UI-Thread, e.g AsyncTask onPostExecute(...)

You may use GSON, which can create Java Objects from JSON mesages automatically. This way you do not have to parse server requests by hand. If you only have *short* running to *middle-long* running server requests, you can consider using Volley for handling all of the above for you, also compatible to GSON.

The more elaborate way is to employ ContentProviders, Authentication- and Sync-Services as demonstrated [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html). But this may be overkill depending on how complex your app is supposed to be. It is advised if you want to offer your content to other apps on the device, e.g. integration with google native search application, and handle your authenatiation/accounts via the settings menu in android system.

Comment: helpful!! can you also provide the link to tutorial for polling technique?

Comment: Of course, for aforementioned short to medium long running operations you use:

Perform Network Operations on a Separate Thread:
[link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask)

Comment: gson will also handle problems arrising from large JSON answers blowing your memory heap up.  gson will serialize the json answer and deal with one jsonobject at a time, as opposed to loading the whole jsonArray, notoriously space consuming situation that it is, in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Database and store the data. Each time you press on a refresh button you can diff the content.

Comment: and that is my question itself, where do I store my database for this purpose and how to fetch data from it?

Comment: Store the db on your internal storage. You can create a db helper to fetch the data.

Comment: This is a very good example: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html